# windows mobile list view

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

I am new to windows mobile application by using c#. I didn't know how to add images and controls in list view can any one give an idea?

Comment: Version ? There are gigantic differences between the API between Windows Phone 7 and earlier Windows Mobile versions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you really mean Windows Mobile (not Windows Phone) What type of "list view" are you talking about?

- For a ListBox, you can do owner-drawing like [this blog](http://blog.opennetcf.com/2007/05/16/sdf-sample-custom-drawing-a-list-and-viewing-all-network-adapters-too/) outlines.
- For a ListView you can do custom drawing, as outlined in [this blog entry](http://christian-helle.blogspot.com/2009/10/listview-custom-drawing-in-netcf.html)

Comment: i want some controls like table view, list view which are used in android and iphone